# Allow login only for one account from one device

Tags: login, code

Hi All i hope all you are ok .
i am working on a membership website , and i want to prevent user from shared there paid account to other people , meaning that the registered account attached to ip so no one can use this account in other device .

Comment: hmm, you should probably duckduckgo what is NAT and how many people use it. If your site is small enough it does not matter and your scheme will work, but as someone who is relatively frequently blocked because the coffeeshop IP was used for "evil" for some silly definition of "evil" the idea is iretating ;). Also devices don't have an IP, and same device might have different IPs in different times of the day, so unless you mean to fore users to login several times a day, this might not be the best idea.

Comment: A better thing and probably not so hard to implememnt, is to prevent a login from users that already have an active login session. You will still most likely will want to handle gracefully notifying the user why it can not login and give him a way to "end" previous sessions.
There are probably prlugin that implementthe basic idea, you may want to look for them, or wait for a more complete answer ;)